# How do you animate the color of text in UWP?

Tags: animation, uwp

I need an example of animating the brush of a text control (TextBlock, TextBox).  When the value of a text block/box changes, I want to highlight it in red, then have it fade to black.  This was easily done in WPF, but I can't find any examples in UWP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In UWP, animation can be set through `Storyboard`. According to your needs, what you want should be `ColorAnimation`.

Here is an example:

**xaml**

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="InputBoxBorderAnimation">
        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:1" From="Red" To="Black" Storyboard.TargetName="MyTextBox"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(MyTextBox.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"/>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
             VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="300" TextChanged="MyTextBox_TextChanged"/>
</Grid>
```

**xaml.cs**

```cs
private void MyTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    InputBoxBorderAnimation.Begin();
}
```

This will change the border color each time you enter text in the text box.

If you want to learn more about UWP animation, these documents may help you:

- [Storyboarded animations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/motion/storyboarded-animations)
- [ColorAnimation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.coloranimation)